# Аналог нативной функции array_unique без использования встроенных функций для работы с массивами

Tags: php

Написать аналог нативной функции array_unique без использования встроенных в PHP функций для работы с массивами. Нужно написать оптимально, т.к. во входящем массиве может быть до 1 000 000 элементов

Мой вариант:

```
// аналог встроенной ф-ции in_array
function myInArray($needle, array $haystack, $strict = false)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($strict ? ($needle === $item) : ($needle == $item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function myArrayUnique(array $array)
{
    $unique_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (!myInArray($item, $unique_array)) {
            $unique_array[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $unique_array;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(myArrayUnique($array));
echo '</pre>';
```

---

### Почему не подходит мой вариант (из комментария)

Мой метод не сохранит ключи например в работе с массивом:

```
$arr = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
```

Результат должен быть:

> Array([a] => green [0] => red [1] => blue).

А мой вариант кода вернет:

> Array( [0] => green [1] => red [2] => blue )

Comment: Как минимум при объявлении параметров используйте &$array иначе при каждом вызове функций массив полностью копируется и что то мне подсказывает, что поиск "было ли" будет быстрее, если будет прямо в фукнции unique, а не вынесен в отдельную. И дальше вопрос сколько ожидается дублей. Возможно быстрее будет делать параллельный хеш в котором отражать какие элементы уже были. поиск по ключу в хеше значительно быстрей перебора массива.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем? Вам нужен был метод, вы его написали.

Comment: мой метод не сохранит ключи например в работе с массивом: $arr = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red"); Результат должен быть: Array([a] => green [0] => red [1] => blue).   А мой вариант кода вернет: Array( [0] => green [1] => red [2] => blue )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если проблема только в ключах, то вот немного измененный код, который вернет и ключи, которые вам нужны (функция `myArrayUnique`):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if (!myInArray($item, $unique_array)) {
        $unique_array[$key] = $item;
    }
}
```

Также я написал другую реализацию нужной функции и сделал небольшой тест производительности для массива с `1000000` элементов:

```
<?php

$array = array();
$size = 1000000;
$min = 1;
$max = 100;

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $array[] = rand($min, $max);
}

function myInArray($needle, array $haystack, $strict = false)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($strict ? ($needle === $item) : ($needle == $item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function myArrayUnique(array $array)
{
    $unique_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (!myInArray($item, $unique_array)) {
            $unique_array[$key] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $unique_array;
}

function myArrayUnique2(array &$array)
{
    $uniqueArray = array();
    $usedItems = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if (empty($usedItems[$item])) {
            $uniqueArray[$key] = $item;
            $usedItems[$item] = true;
        }
    }

    return $uniqueArray;
}

$start = microtime(true);
$result = myArrayUnique($array);
$timeElapsedSecs = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "Test 1: {$timeElapsedSecs} sec \n";

$start = microtime(true);
$result = myArrayUnique2($array);
$timeElapsedSecs = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "Test 2: {$timeElapsedSecs} sec \n";
```

На моей системе результат был такой:

```
$ php test.php
Test 1: 10.178105831146 sec
Test 2: 0.10400199890137 sec
```

Т.е. ускорение примерно в 100 раз по сравнению с вашим вариантом. Примененные в моем варианте оптимизации вам уже указывали в первом комментарии.

Comment: Очень помогли, спасибо ))   Только пока не совсем понял как работает эта часть if (empty($usedItems[$item])) {
            $uniqueArray[$key] = $item;
            $usedItems[$item] = true;
        }

Comment: В $usedItems просто помещаются уже использованные члены исходного массива. Массив приобретает вид [item1=>true, item2=>true, item3=>true,.., itemN=>true]. Т.е. использованные члены являются индексами этого массива, а потому мы можем легко проверять их наличие без циклов этой проверкой: `empty($usedItems[$item])`. Если элемента в массиве использованных значений нет (условие `false`), то мы его добавляем. Ответ также можно отметить полезным, если он вам помог;)